# Output from ob_get_clean() is truncated at 1024 characters?

Tags: php, output-buffering, truncation

I'm working on someone elses code and there is ~800 lines of markup mixed in with  tags.  I'm trying to apply some templates to these pages and I thought I would start by capturing all the output in an output buffer, return that as a variable and then sort things out piece by piece.

The problem is that at the end of the buffer when I return the output as a string it is truncated at 1024 characters.  Why would this be?

Comment: I just checked the php.ini file and the memory_limit is set to 32 mb so I doubt that's it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, it doesn't do that, which could mean:

1. There is another `ob_start($callback)` with a specific callback active messing things up (what does `ob_get_level` say?).
2. There is erroneous manipulation after the `ob_get_clean()`
3. There are erroneous checking methods involved, and the 1024 cut-off is incorrect (xdebug's limit on var_dump's, hidden content in html-attributes & not looking at the source, etc.)

Those 3 are about it, without code there isn't much else to say.

Answer (score 0):

These 1024 bytes might not be the beginning of the output. Some content might already have passed the output buffer. For testing purposes try:

```
ob_start(NULL, 1<<20);  // 1MB buffer

echo ...;

$all = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Also test with [`ob_get_flush()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php) instead. If all else fails, use a custom ob_ handler.